# Test Suggestion log error

Tags: content-search, content-testing

Log showing message as “Error Occurred” when page displayed in edit mode.
Un-commented the definition of Sitecore_suggested_test_index. The error is not showing up now. Is this index needs to be disabled/enabled for SXA sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is related to the **Sitecore Suggested Tests** functionality (related to the MV [A/B] testing).

If you disable the **suggested_test_index** this feature can't function properly, thus you are receiving various errors (especially in the Exp. Editor)

To cut it short:

1. If you want to use the content (a/b or MV) testing feature, just keep the index and everything related to the Content Testing enabled.
2. If you want to disable that, please follow this official Sitecore guide to disable the content testing ([link](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/785358))